# JQuery.one() event that fires immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a jquery plugin in which you can set the event for something to happen.

```
$.fn.makeSomething = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        activationEvent: "mouseover"
    };
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    this.each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.one(options.activationEvent, function(){
            // some code to be called at the event (in which I use elem)
            // but by default should be called immediately on load
        });
    });

    return this;
}
```

I would like the default to be that it just happens without any needed interaction. Is this possible?

A little more info:

I have several divs in which some extra content should be loaded. By default I want the content to be loaded when the page loads. However, on some pages I don't want all the content to be loaded with the page, but I want each piece to be loaded only when you hover your mouse over its div.

Thanks!

Comment: You could call the function when the page loads.

Comment: `if(options.activationEvent){$(this).one(options.activationEvent,function(){}} else {$(this).fireEvent()}`.  If you want to have it happen when the user includes..just do what @JayBlanchard said, and call it with no parameters.

Comment: Are you wanting something that runs when the page loads and then again when the event occurs but only once per element?

Comment: I added some more info on what I'm trying to do. What user1167442 suggested works, then I just set the default activationEvent to `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you separate the `function` definition from the binding:

```
$.fn.makeSomething = function(options) {
    // ...

    function doSomething() {
        // ...
    }

    $(this).one(options.activationEvent, doSomething);
};
```

You can test the `activationEvent` for a default value that isn't an event, such as `null`, providing the that same function to `.each()`:

```
$.fn.makeSomething = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        activationEvent: null
    };
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    function doSomething() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        // ...
    }

    if (!options.activationEvent)
        this.each(doSomething);
    else
        this.one(options.activationEvent, doSomething);
};
```

```
// act immediately
$('...').makeSomething();
```

```
// act on mouseover
$('...').makeSomething({ activationEvent: 'mouseover' });
```

Both `.one()` and `.each()` will invoke `doSomething()` with `this` referring to the DOM Element. (Note: the arguments provided to `doSomething()` will, however, be different.)